# Please help with creating gunicorn systemd Service File

Tags: server, nginx

I developed simple web page using django and for second week struggling trying to launch it. I have no background in server managing so everything I do is new to me. During my trials I have read countless tutorials and did not managed to get my website up and running (and it drives me insane). For now I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). I am at the part there I need to create `Gunicorn systemd Service File`, but because my project structure is little bit different I can't figure way how to do it correctly.

My project structure would be like this:
`user: gdmin`

Everything held in parent folder named `skdir` and in subfolders within in it. Below I tried to visualize it in tree view structure (not all files shown, just the ones i thought important):

```
skdir/
     myenv/
          bin/
             gunicorn    
     STV_skaiciuokle/
                    skaiciuokle_web/
                                   manage.py
                                   skaiciuokle_web/
                                                  settings.py
                                   static/
                                         js
                                         css
                                         img
                                   media
```

To make everything more clear my manage.py file is in `skdir/STV_skaiciuokle/skaiciuokle_web` directory.

My current `gunicorn.service` configured like this (not working):

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=gdmin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/gdmin/skdir
ExecStart=/home/gdmin/skdir/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/gdmin/skdir/STV_skaiciuokle/skaiciuokle_web/skaiciuokle_web.sock skaiciuokle_web.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How should I correct it?

Also can somebody recommend good tutorial on this, something like "deploy Django for dummies" level?

Comment: I crossposted this question on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/please-help-with-creating-gunicorn-systemd-service-file if ill get answer there, I will post it in here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it running myself.

Problem was that socket file was not being created. During my research I noticed that **init**.py files were not present since then I uploaded my project to github it discarded them as empty and unnecessary. I fixed this and it seems that was the root of my problem in the first place. After this I finally got site up and running.

To think about it, probably this was a problem all along and other tutorials probably would had worked also...